# Continuous Deployment with jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile, spring-boot

I am a beginner in DevOps.
I created a continuous integration cycle using jenkins(docker image) and bitbucket.
I used a simple spring boot hello-world project and after CI i got an executable Jar.
I created a dockerfile and docker-compose for the deployment process.
I tried this on my local server and it worked successfully(hello world successfully displayed on browser).
Now i want to begin the continuous deployment process on remote server how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your next step will be to identify a solution for *container orchestration*.  For a quick dev test solution, you could host your [own docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/), push your built image to the registry, and add a deployment step that stops the existing container and spins up a new one from your registry.

However, in a production setting there are many other aspects to consider such as downtime, versioning, security, etc.  There are several products and tools that are designed to handle containers such as [AWS Elastic Container Solution (ECS)](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc&ecs-blogs.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&ecs-blogs.sort-order=desc), [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/).

Comment: thanks a lot ! Kubernetes sounds interesting i came across it when i was following docker tutorials